# Rust embedded: bytes to string

Tags: rust, embedded

In older versions of [heapless](https://docs.rs/heapless/latest/heapless/) there was a from_utf8 method but it has been removed.
How do you convert bytes to string in a embedded system (no std)?

Comment: So when you say #![no_std] you can still use rust core, right? This provides `core::str::from_utf8`

Comment: @JuliusKreutz: Indeed, [`heapless::String::as_bytes()`](https://docs.rs/heapless/latest/heapless/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes) suggests to use `core::str::from_utf8()` to do the opposite conversion. Probably that is why their own implementation was removed.